# Not able to call URI in Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This is is my spring-servlet.xml code

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">        


<context:component-scan base-package="com.devlan.userportal" />
 </beans>
```

My web.xml is

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

And my controller is

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/users"})
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
public User findOne(@PathVariable("id") int id){
    return userService.findById(id);
}
```

But here always it shows me a message

```
[WARNING ] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MyProject/users/1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

I gave the context scan tag in spring-servlet.xml

Am I missing anything? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you take out "/MyProject" from the URL?  Maybe you haven't set up the context root for your web app...

Comment: @moilejter Only the home page works.. But not able to point to the specified url

Comment: Is the controller class in the package scope of `com.devlan.userportal` or a package level above?

Comment: The controller is available in the same package